# iTunes Connect Reserve Name Limit

Tags: ios, app-store-connect

I am arriving on my 180 day limit and I received an email that I need to upload my binary before that or I will lose the name. I am really close to actually releasing but I'm not 100% sure I can make the 7 day deadline. I just submitted my binary and it was rejected (some missing screenshots) is that sufficient enough to "reset the clock"? Is there anywhere I can check to make sure I'm not losing the name in 7 days?

Comment: How did it go, which tactic was sufficient to reset the clock?

Comment: @Hooman I emailed them and they gave me a "one time" extension.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quickly upload a runnable version and immediately reject it yourself. That will give you some extra months. For app info like description and screenshots you can upload some placeholders temporarily.

The important thing is to reject it yourself.

Comment: Ok thanks, I'll do that. I intentionally didn't add screenshots hoping that was sufficient.